# Remove repeating characters from string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, character

I have a string, like e.g. `acaddef` or `bbaaddgg`. I have to remove from it, as fast as possible, all repeating characters. So, for example, `pooaatat` after should look like `poat` and `ggaatpop` should look like `gatpo`. Is there any built-in function or algorithm to do that quickly? I tried to search STL, but without satisfaing result.

Comment: Slicing strings requires knowing the character set and encoding (and any simplifying assumptions/input validation you want to apply to your algorithm). Are you using Unicode/UTF-8? (For console programs, on Linus run: `locale`, on Windows: `chcp`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so here are 4 different solutions.

## Fixed Array

```
std::string str = "pooaatat";

// Prints "poat"
short count[256] = {0};
std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
             [&](unsigned char c) { return count[c]++ == 0; });
```

## Count Algorithm + Iterator

```
std::string str = "pooaatat";

// Prints "poat"
std::string::iterator iter = str.begin();
std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
             [&](char c) { return !std::count(str.begin(), iter++, c); });
```

## Unordered Set

```
std::string str = "pooaatat";

// Prints "poat"
std::unordered_set<char> container;
std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
             [&](char c) { return container.insert(c).second; });
```

## Unordered Map

```
std::string str = "pooaatat";

// Prints "poat"
std::unordered_map<char, int> container;
std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
             [&](char c) { return container[c]++ == 0; });
```

Comment: It should print "poat", because double "t" also should be removed

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no built-in algorithm for doing this. The `std::unique` algorithm is valid if you want to remove only consecutive duplicate characters.

However you can follow the following simple approach:

If the string contains only ASCII characters, you can form a boolean array A[256] denoting whether the respective character has been encountered already or not.

Then simply traverse the input string and copy the character to output if A[character] is still 0 (and make A[character] = 1).

In case the string contains arbitrary characters, then you can use a `std::unordered_map` or a `std::map` of char to int.

Comment: ASCII contains only 128 codepoints and is largely irrelevant. With your 256 element array, the restriction is only that the character set have at most 256 codepoints, that each has a 1-byte encoding and that there are no "combining characters," which would need to be kept with preceding codepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in regular expressions should be efficient, i.e.

```
#include <regex>
[...]

const std::regex pattern("([\\w ])(?!\\1)");
string s = "ssha3akjssss42jj 234444 203488842882387 heeelloooo";
std::string result;

for (std::sregex_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), pattern), end; i != end; ++i)
    result.append((*i)[1]);

std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Of course, you can modify the cpaturing group to your needs.
The good thing is that it is supported in Visual Studio 2010 tr1 already. gcc 4.8, however, seems to have a [problem](http://ideone.com/fibwIr) with regex iterators.